# Where is Goose from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

Where is Goose, the Flerken with the bag-of-holding gullet originally from?

[image: Goose]

She is originally named Chewie in the comics.

Comment: I see that someone is suggesting this is unclear; maybe you could clarify if you're asking where Mar-Vell got *her* from or if you're asking about her planet of origin.

Comment: Originally - as in origin? Is there another way to define that? I'm confused.

Comment: I think a good answer would have both if there's a difference, right?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what might satisfy the person who wants to close this as unclear.  Goose may not have been born/hatched on her species' homeworld, so maybe that's a difference?  I dunno, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Close votes with no comment aren't very useful in improving the site

Comment: To those trying to anonymously close this question it's not likely to become any more clear, "where is X from " has been asked many times and is generally a straightforward question. Like [this one for Madam Gao](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86921/where-is-madam-gao-from?rq=1), or [this one for Yondu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79626/where-does-yondu-of-the-ravagers-come-from?rq=1). Just leave a comment please if any of this is confusing and I can explain what originally means.

Comment: Whilst I don't agree with the close votes here, not every close vote needs an explanation. Some are just self explanatory so don't require a comment. Worth keeping in mind. And of course people are not obligated to comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the MCU we don’t know, we have very little information on Goose and Flerkens in general. What we do know is that Wendy Lawson, aka Mar-Vell, had Goose with her. She seems to be somewhat knowledgable of the animal and knows more about her than the others, such as Goose taking to Carol.

> **Wendy Lawson:** Goose likes you. She doesn't typically take to people.
>
> <sub>*Captain Marvel*</sub>

Presumably then Mar-Vell brought Goose with her to Earth when she started working on the engine there. Before that though her origins are unclear and unexplained.

It is worth noting though that there has been interest to know more of the Flerken’s backstory and Kevin Feige has previously stated the potential of doing something for Disney+. So we may get an answer in the form of something on there at some point.

> **I’m wondering what has Goose been doing for the last 20 years? Can we get like a short film on Disney+ where we would like see that Goose was secretly offscreen at all of these important events?**
>
> I love it! And by the way, that’s one of the fun things about Disney+ is we could actually do ideas like that. The fun thing about introducing new characters and all these movies is suddenly going from a character that maybe you’d heard of if you’d read the books, but if you hadn’t, you’d never heard of him. And then you see the movie, you go, “I want to see more of that character.” And the fact that you and other people are asking, “When do we see more of the cat?” The question is “how long – what is the lifespan of a flerken?” It’s a good question.
>
> <sub>[Slash Film, Interview: Kevin Feige Talks ‘Captain Marvel’ Spoilers, The Future of Goose, Stan Lee’s Tribute, and Disney+ TV Shows](https://www.slashfilm.com/kevin-feige-captain-marvel-interview/)</sub>